# Trouble on problem with Multiples in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Sorry i am a beginner and having a lot of trouble. i appreciate any help. The question is "Implement a function, multiples(m, n), which returns an array of the first m multiples of the real number n. Assume that m is a positive integer."

My code is:

```
def multiples(m, n):
    multiples_list = []
    while m > 0:
        multiples = m * n
        m -= 1
        multiples_list.append(multiples)
    return multiples_list
```

The trouble is 1) my list is backwards 2) i feel like my code feels pretty ineffecient

thanks

Comment: You can use a "for in range(1, m + 1)"-loop to repeat the code m times with m always set appropriately. There is also a way to write your function in a single line (plus "def" line) but I think this isn't the point here.

Comment: It would help if you say why you feel your code is "inefficient", and what you are considering your metric for efficiency

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good place to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
def multiples(m,n):
    return [i*n for i in range(1,m+1)]
```